# Odd behavior with sc:link

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore

I have the following code in a rendering, running on multiple environments:

```html
<li class="formWWW">
    <span class="formNumber"><sc:text field="Form Number" /></span>
    <h4><sc:link field="URL"><sc:text field="Title" /></sc:link></h4>
    <p><xsl:value-of select="sc:fld('Description', .)" /></p>
</li>
```

The issue I'm having involves the `<sc:link>` inside the h4. On my local machine and in our development environment, it properly generates an anchor tag the way it is supposed to; however, in our QA testing environment, it seems as though `<sc:link>` is just dumping the contents of the URL (General Link) field instead of rendering it as an anchor. It is very confusing since I know the renderings and the data inside the fields are both consistent among the environments.

My best guess is that there is a configuration setting somewhere relating to the behavior of `<sc:link>`, but I don't know. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you mean its dumping the raw values from the GL field?

Comment: Yes, I do. I actually had the server team reset IIS and everything started working.. I guess that's the lesson here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought about just deleting this question, but it may be useful for others down the line to know that the problem was solved by resetting IIS. It seems as though whenever nothing makes sense, iisreset.